# Can one travel from Metro Manila to somewhere else in Philippines outside Metro Manila via another country during the COVID-19 Metro Manila lockdown?

Tags: international-travel, philippines, covid-19, manila, travel-ban

Can one travel from Metro Manila to somewhere else in Philippines outside Metro Manila via another country during the COVID-19 Metro Manila lockdown? Or is it against the Metro Manila lockdown rules and would lead to being refused entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technically possible, but in practice very difficult unless you're a citizen.**

While some international flights to/from the Philippines continue to operate, there have been massive capacity reductions, both to Manila and other destinations.

More importantly, the Philippines have also **banned foreign visitors from countries with "local coronavirus transmission"**, an ill-defined group that is likely to cover virtually every larger country.  This doesn't apply to Philippine nationals and residents though: http://www.cnnphilippines.com/news/2020/3/12/Philippines-expands-travel-ban-to-all-countries-with-local-COVID-19-transmission.html

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up: [Where I find the up-to-date list of countries with “local coronavirus transmission” that Philippines banned foreign visitors from?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155021/1810)