# Where I can find the up-to-date list of countries with "local coronavirus transmission" that Philippines banned foreign visitors from?

Tags: international-travel, online-resources, philippines, covid-19, travel-ban

I read in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154997/1810) by  [lambshaanxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/lambshaanxy):

> the Philippines have also banned foreign visitors from countries with "local coronavirus transmission"

Where can I find the up-to-date list of countries with "local coronavirus transmission" that Philippines banned foreign visitors from?

Answer (score 2):

Hei
According to this [article](https://www.rappler.com/nation/254274-philippines-bans-foreigners-novel-coronavirus-hit-countries), the philippines react to the list provided by the WHO.
On The [WHO website](https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/685d0ace521648f8a5beeeee1b9125cd) you can get this worldmap with the updated cases and countries.
This [website](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) gives you also a realtime overview band is backed by DADAX, an independent company with no political, governmental, or corporate affiliation.

Have a nice day and I hope I matched your question.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation available online only mentions restrictions affecting China, Korea, Italy and Iran. But it's possible immigration officers have other information.

Confusingly the announcement of the restrictions on March 12 mentioned "countries with local coronavirus transmission", but the document implementing this announcement mentions Italy and Iran but no other countries. That official document from the office of the president, dated March 13, is found here https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/section/laws/executive-issuances/memoranda/ .
A press release (dated March 13/14) from the bureau of immigration http://www.immigration.gov.ph/#press-release also mentions only Italy and Iran, in addition to the earlier restrictions affecting travel from China (including Hong Kong and Macau) and South Korea (only North Gyeongsang province).
The Department of Foreign Affairs https://www.dfa.gov.ph/dfa-news/statements-and-advisoriesupdate has documents about these earlier restrictions but not (yet?) about the more recent ones.

Travelers will also be affected by the local near-lockdowns in and around Manila (office of the President, March 13), Luzon (office of the President, March 16) and Cebu (provincial government, March 14), and other places. And of course the situation can change any time now.